# Domain classes relations query not working after upgrade grails from 1.3.7 to 2.2.2

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am upgrading my grails apps from grails version 1.3.7 to 2.2.2. I made most of codes working except this one. The same code working in grails 1.3.7 but stop working and get errors in grails 2.2.2. Please help.  Here are the classes cause the issue.
Domain class User, UserConfig, and Service class UserService.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  String id
  ...
  static hasMany = [userConfigs:UserConfig]

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table 'c_user'
    id column: 'id'
  }

}
public class UserConfig implements Serializable
{
    UserProfile profile
    String genesysUserId

    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'sp_user_config'
        id composite:['user', 'profile']
        user column: 'user_id'
        profile column: 'profile_id', lazy: false
    }
}

public class UserService {

    boolean transactional = true

    def getUserList(groupIdList) {

        def userList = User.list()

        userList.findAll() { user ->
            user.userConfigs?.find() { userConfig ->
                        groupIdList.contains(userConfig?.profile?.group?.id)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got Class; java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: argument type mismatch 
 in class UserService.groovy at line

`user.userConfigs?.find() { userConfig->` 
and line `userList.findAll() { user->`

If I add 'List userConfigs'  to User domain class as

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  String id
  List<UserConfig> userConfigs
  ...
  static hasMany = [userConfigs:UserConfig]

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table 'c_user'
    id column: 'id'
  }

}
```

I got Class : java.sql.SQLException
Message: ORA-00904: "USERCONFIG0_"."USER_CONFIGS_IDX": invalid identifier from the same class UserService and same line of code.

Is this the new version of grails' issue or hibernate issue?

Comment: Please, post full stacktrace and the service code.

Comment: Are you using `@TypeChecked` in the service method?

Comment: I am not using @TypeChecked annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, and the easiest, is if you have the children as a list (List in this case) hibernate expects to see an index column in the table so it knows where in the list to put each child. The SQL exception there seems to point to that.

As for the first issue it doesn't seem to be a hibernate one, since you are just iterating over already loaded objects. You didn't include UserProfile so not sure if it has anything to do with that object.

My first step would be to throw in some logging into those closures and see what's happening. Or if you a debugger fan, use that.

Comment: It's interesting that the same piece of code in UserService can be run successfully in Grails Console. Is

Comment: It's very interesting to find that the same piece of codes in the UserService class can be successfully without issue. So is that possible tomcat plugin issue?

Comment: comment out the line "List<UserConfig> userConfigs" and see if that works. or, add in the column that oracle is complaining about